# Kubernetes: No Route to Host

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have a Bare-Metal Kubernetes custom setup (manually setup cluster using Kubernetes the Hard Way). Everything seems to work, but I cannot access services externally.

I can get the list of services when curl:

```
https://<ip-addr>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services
```

However, when I try to proxy (using `kubectl proxy`, and also by using the `<master-ip-address>:<port>`):

```
https://<ip-addr>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/toned-gecko-grafana:80/proxy/
```

I get:

```
Error: 'dial tcp 10.44.0.16:3000: connect: no route to host'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.44.0.16:3000/'
```

- <strike>Even if I normally curl `http://10.44.0.16:3000/` I get the same error. This is the result whether I curl from inside the VM where Kubernetes is installed.</strike> Was able to resolve this, check below.
- I can access my services externally using NodePort.
- I can access my services if I expose them through Nginx-Ingress.
- I am using Weave as CNI, and the logs were normal except a couple of log-lines at the beginning about it not being able to access Namespaces (RBAC error). Though logs were fine after that.
- Using CoreDNS, logs look normal. APIServer and Kubelet logs look normal. Kubernetes-Events look normal, too.
- ***Additional Note***: The DNS Service-IP I assigned is `10.3.0.10`, and the service IP range is: `10.3.0.0/24`, and POD Network is `10.2.0.0/16`. I am not sure what `10.44.x.x` is or where is it coming from.

  - Also, I am using Nginx-Ingress (Helm Chart: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress)

Here is output from one of the services:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
    "namespace": "kube-system",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard",
    "uid": "5c8bb34f-c6a2-11e8-84a7-00163cb4ceeb",
    "resourceVersion": "7054",
    "creationTimestamp": "2018-10-03T00:22:07Z",
    "labels": {
      "addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode": "Reconcile",
      "k8s-app": "kubernetes-dashboard",
      "kubernetes.io/cluster-service": "true"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Service\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode\":\"Reconcile\",\"k8s-app\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\",\"kubernetes.io/cluster-service\":\"true\"},\"name\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\"},\"spec\":{\"ports\":[{\"port\":443,\"targetPort\":8443}],\"selector\":{\"k8s-app\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\"}}}\n"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 443,
        "targetPort": 8443,
        "nodePort": 30033
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "k8s-app": "kubernetes-dashboard"
    },
    "clusterIP": "10.3.0.30",
    "type": "NodePort",
    "sessionAffinity": "None",
    "externalTrafficPolicy": "Cluster"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {

    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to debug this, even some pointers to the right direction would help. If anything else is required, please let me know.

---

Output from `kubectl get svc`:

```
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
coredns-primary        ClusterIP   10.3.0.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   4h51m
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort    10.3.0.30    <none>        443:30033/TCP            4h51m
```

---

**EDIT:**

Turns out I didn't have `kube-dns` service running for some reason, despite having CoreDNS running. It was as mentioned here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1056#issuecomment-413235119

Now I can curl from inside the VM successfully, but the proxy-access still gives me the same error: `No route to host`. I am not sure why or how would this fix the issue, since I don't see DNS being in play here, but it fixed the issue regardles. Would appreciate any possible explanation on this too.

Comment: When you proxy do you mean using `kubectl proxy`? or just the proxy endpoint. Where are you running your `curl` requests from?  Can you also post some output for `kubectl get svc`

Comment: By `proxy`, I meant `kubectl proxy` and `https://<master-id-addr>:<port>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/toned-gecko-grafana:80/proxy/`

Curl request as run inside the VM on which the Kubernetes is installed. I have posted the output of `kubectl get svc` above in question.

Comment: Did going through `kubectl proxy` work before and not it doesn't work?

Comment: No, it never worked. I just setup my cluster a few hours ago.... Also, I updated the question, please check the final part/edit.

Comment: Also, post your `kubectl proxy` command

Comment: `kubectl proxy --port=9001 --address='<ip-addr>' --accept-hosts="^*$"`. Here `<ip-addr>` is the address of Worker-server on which K8s Dashboard and other serivces are hosted (that's what I am trying to access).

Comment: Can you just do `kubectl proxy` only to talk to the apiserver? It should pick up the config under `~/.kube/config`

Comment: Yes, that works. I was able to access API endpoints-list and get service-names from server.

EDIT: However, when I run `curl localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/` from within VM, I get `No route to Host`.

Comment: So everything works fine except contacting services externally. I am able to hit API-Server and get the response. But as soon as I access any service via proxy such as `localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`, I get the `No route to host`.

Comment: I don't know if you can...

Comment: It does say in the docs that you should be able to: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#master-server

Unless I am missing something...

Comment: Oh yeah, the dashboard. tbh not really sure what's going on.

Comment: I see, thanks for the attempt anyway. Hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same issue and resolved it by running the commands below:

```
iptables --flush
iptables -tnat --flush
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: FYI this disables the firewall and is not a good option for security

Comment: Just flushing iptables (so first two commands) was enough in my case.

Answer (score 4):

for me the the solution was to modify the rules in iptables as described [here](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/854)

```
sudo iptables -D  INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
sudo iptables -D  FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to run `curl https://<master-ip-address>:<port>`.

If port is open you should receive a message related to certificate or HTTPS.

**It port is closed (which is probably the issue in your case)** - the `no route to host` message appears.

**(!) Do not disable iptables.**

Open the port by SSH-ing into master node and running: 
A ) `sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=<relevant-port>/tcp --permanent` (I'm assuming `firewalld` is installed).

B ) `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`.

C ) `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all` - you should see `<relevant-port>` is updated.

```
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: <relevant-port>/tcp <---- Here
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu-based hosts don't have `firewall-cmd` installed.  You can try `ufw` to manage the `iptables`, but it creates its own set of rules that might conflict with the existing `iptables` rules.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `kubectl proxy`, by default you should use `127.0.0.1:8001` as HTTP Kube API URL. Your requests to `http://127.0.0.1:8001` are then augmented with authentication headers and passed to API server. Thus you should try `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/toned-gecko-grafana:80/proxy/` rather then with https and api ip

Also, make sure you have socat installed on kube nodes.